# How to deal with error "could not find react-redux context value"?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router-dom

I need to move redux `Provider` from index.js to App.jsx.
When it was set in index.js, it was working fine, but I was asked to set it in the `App` component.
The working state is the below:

index.js

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { HashRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import store from "./redux/store/index";

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/*" element={<App />} />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("app")
);
```

App.jsx

```
return (
  <Routes>
    {isLoggedIn ? (
      <Route path="/" element={<Home onLogout={logout} />}>
        <Route index element={<Information />} />
        <Route path="users" element={<UserList />} />
      </Route>
    ) : (
      <Route path="/login" element={<Login onLogin={login} />} />
    )}
  </Routes>
);
```

redux store

```js
import { createStore, combineReducers } from "redux";
import authReducer from "../reducers/authReducer";
import informationReducer from "../reducers/informationReducers";
import userListReducer from "../reducers/userListReducer";

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  auth: authReducer,
  information: informationReducer,
  userList: userListReducer,
});

const store = createStore(rootReducer);
export default store;
```

When I moved it to `App` component, I got an error in the console, and nothing mounts.

> Uncaught Error: could not find react-redux context value; please
> ensure the component is wrapped in a `<Provider>`

Below is the after moving Provider to App component

index.js

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("app")
);
```

App.jsx

```
function App() {
  const isLoggedIn = useSelector((state) => state.auth.isLoggedIn);

  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const login = () => {
    dispatch(login());
    navigate("/", { replace: true });
  };

  const logout = () => {
    dispatch(logout());
    navigate("/login", { replace: true });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const refresh_token = localStorage.getItem("refresh_token");

    if (!refresh_token) {
      navigate("/login");
      return;
    }

    axiosInstance
      .get("/auth/refresh", {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${refresh_token}`,
        },
      })
      .then(() => {
        dispatch(login());
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        navigate("/login");
        localStorage.clear();
        return Promise.reject(error);
      });
  }, [dispatch, navigate]);

  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Router>
        <Routes>
          {isLoggedIn ? (
            <Route path="/" element={<Home onLogout={logout} />}>
              <Route index element={<Information/>} />
              <Route path="users" element={<UsersList />} />
            </Route>
          ) : (
            <Route path="/login" element={<Login onLogin={login} />} />
          )}
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </Provider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

As a test, I deleted all the code from router and subsequent children, and just put a simple in between the provider, and no error occured

```
return (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <div> TEST </div>
  </Provider>
);
```

What could be the problem?
Are my routes not set properly?
react-redux: 7.2.6,
react-router-dom: 6.2.1
react: 17.0.2
redux: 4.1.2

Comment: Looks like `App` is trying to access the Redux context (*I suspect for the `isLoggedIn` value???*). Please [edit] to share a complete [mcve] so we can see what the code is trying to do, e.g. everything in `App` above the return statement. ***Why*** do you need to move the `Provider` component? What is the issue with it in `index.js`?

Comment: No idea. I was just told to move the provider and the the routing to app component

Comment: Well, `<Route path="/*" element={<App />} />` is completely unnecessary, you can simply render `<App />` directly inside `Provider`. `App` can't render the `Provider` if it is trying to select state from the store. The context needs to be provided from higher up the ReactTree.

Comment: yea, `<Route path="/*" element={<App />} />` is gone. That was the before code

Comment: So, there is no way to set the `Provider` in the `App` component?

Comment: No, there certainly is, but it depends on what `App` is doing. We can't see that part of the code though to say why it is or isn't working. I suspect `isLoggedIn` is being selected from the store, and so if you need to push the `Provider` *down* the ReactTree into `App` then you'll need to also push the selection of `isLoggedIn` further down the ReactTree. If you can share the complete `App` code we can provide a suggestion.

Comment: will add the complete `App` file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `App` component can't render the Redux `Provider` component ***and*** attempt to select state from it. The context necessarily needs to be provided from higher up the ReactTree.

The problem is `const isLoggedIn = useSelector((state) => state.auth.isLoggedIn);` in `App`. If pushing `Provider` down into `App` then the selection of `isLoggedIn` ***also*** needs to be pushed down. Fortunately this is trivial to solve and also leads to a more commonly used route protection implementation.

Create `PrivateRoutes` and `AnonymousRoutes` components that read the `isLoggedIn` state and handle protecting the routes.

Example:

```
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { Navigate, Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

export const PrivateRoutes = () => {
  const isLoggedIn = useSelector((state) => state.auth.isLoggedIn);

  if (isLoggedIn === undefined) {
    return null; // or loading indicator/spinner/etc
  }

  return isLoggedIn
    ? <Outlet />
    : <Navigate to="/login" replace />;

};
```

```
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { Navigate, Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

export const AnonymousRoutes = () => {
  const isLoggedIn = useSelector((state) => state.auth.isLoggedIn);

  if (isLoggedIn === undefined) {
    return null; // or loading indicator/spinner/etc
  }

  return isLoggedIn
    ? <Navigate to="/" replace />
    : <Outlet />;
};
```

App

```
function App() {
  ...

  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route element={<PrivateRoutes />}>
            <Route path="/" element={<Home onLogout={logout} />}>
              <Route index element={<Information/>} />
              <Route path="users" element={<UsersList />} />
            </Route>
          </Route>
          <Route element={<AnonymousRoutes />}>
            <Route path="/login" element={<Login onLogin={login} />} />
          </Route>
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </Provider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time(again) for explaining to me the problem. You make very good explanations. God bless you

Comment: I tried your solution, and so far it is working. Just need to run some other checks, a\but I think its all good

Comment: @raio Welcome, glad to help. I'm sure this will work for your scenario, but if you find an issue with it please just let me know and I'll investigate and adjust. If all is well, then cheers and good luck!

Comment: All seems good man. Thank you so much

Comment: i ran into a small problem tho, and could not figure out why it is happening. When i refresh the page, it always goes to "/" path page.  Staying in the same page is a requirement. Any idea whats going on?

Comment: @raio What route are you on when you reload the page? Other than the `login` function and the `AnonymousRoutes` component I don't see anything in the code that navigates to `"/"`.

Comment: In private routes, `Information` component is the index element. Only if I could show you the final result, so you can analyze. I'm missing something, don't know what. Working on it tho

Comment: ` return isLoggedIn ? <Navigate to="/" replace /> : <Outlet />;` Thats the private routes. Instead of `<Navigate to="/"`, I would like it to go to the page that refresh happened. Tried `location.pathname` but the way my app is structured, even when using `useEffect`, and I switch page, `location.pathname` does not change.

Comment: @raio What is the initial `state.auth.isLoggedIn` state value? If it is initially a defined falsey value then the `isLoggedIn === undefined` condition will evaluate false and the redirect may be effected prior to any actual auth status confirmation completing.